# Ajax is driving me nuts. Why is Jquery post method failing in this specific case?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Ok, so ajax seems to be misbehaving. In other words i'm doing something wrong. I have a simple angular js app. The html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/form_controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="EditDocApp">
        <div ng-controller="EventDetector">
            <input ng-model="event">
            <button ng-click = "SelectEvent()">Click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

form_controllers.js contains a call to the Jquery post method in the EventHandle angular service. This is invoked in the calling of EventHandle.ajaxRequest() in the $scope.SelectEvent method in the EventDetector controller. This is form_controllers.js:

```
var editDocApp = angular.module("EditDocApp", []);

editDocApp.controller("EventDetector", eventDetector)
          .factory("HandleEvents",  handleEvents);

function handleEvents() {
    var pass_back = {
        ajaxLastReturn: "one",
        ajaxRequest: function() { 
            $.post("http://localhost/TrailGuide/Website/Interface/webDataModelBuild/Documentation/scripts/test1.php", {}, function(response) { alert(response); })
             .fail(function() { alert("nah"); });
        }
    }

    return pass_back;
}

function eventDetector($scope, HandleEvents) {

    $scope.event = "";

    $scope.SelectEvent = function() {
        $scope.event = "select";
        HandleEvents.ajaxRequest();
    };  
}
```

The $.post method is failing every time i execute it by calling $scope.SelectEvent() from the button in the view (an alert box with "nah" pops up). I've tested the address passed to $.post by copying and pasting to the browser address box and it runs fine. I've tried the $.post method with and without data, no dice. I've tried jquery.ajax, still no dice. The php file, test1.php, is as follows:

```
<?php
    echo "I am here!";
?>
```

Can somebody please point out what i am missing here? Is there some setting in php.ini that could be effecting this? Btw, this is my very first post on stack overflow so go easy on me! I'll get the hang of it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Follow the call using the network tab on your browser's developer tools. What is the error code returned by the request?

Comment: Is this because your response is not json encoded? Perhaps you need to specify the response format?

Comment: jQuery wouldn't fail due to it not being json encoded unless you specified the json datatype or the server returned with application/json.

Comment: Instead of alerting the useless 'fail' methjod try alerting the fail reasons.

Comment: Quick sanity check: if you visit `http://localhost/TrailGuide/Website/Interface/webDataModelBuild/Documentation/scripts/test1.php` in your browser, do you see the "I am here!"? But yes, as others have said, it's pretty easy to debug the response to find out what's going on these days...

Comment: Oh crap, thanks! Can not believe i didn't think of that. Turns out it's a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."  I can take care of it from here.

Comment: In other words i was making the ajax request from the file:// domain to localhost. It was a cross-domain request. Lesson learned!